# Check if a post is 15 minutes old

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, comparison

So I have a big problem that I need to fix, and research has not yet seemed to help me. I want to change a MySQL table row if the post was made 15 minutes ago. How can I do this?

This is what I've tried:

```
$query_set_invisible = "UPDATE scrims SET available='1' WHERE time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_set_invisible)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

And:

```
$query_set_invisible = "UPDATE scrims SET available='1' WHERE time > DATE_SUB(NOW(),     INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_set_invisible)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: How is this not working?

Comment: @MarcB Im not sure but it isnt changing the row in the mysql table

Comment: then check for execution failure, check `->affected_rows`, check if you actually HAVE records that meet the specified conditions, etc... Because on the face of it, there's nothing wrong with your code, other than a blind assumption that everything'll work perfectly.

Comment: @MarcB Well I know I have records that are within the time range because I made on. I also forgot to say that sometimes the code works and sometimes it doesn't. Could this be a problem with the webhost?

Comment: Two things: 1. Date have no meaning until you use them. 2. The data have the meaning depends how you are interpret them. So you haven't need to update your table, instead, you can filter your data by availability predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here.

1. You're concealing API failures.
2. `time` is a reserved word. You might want to escape it. It should work OK, but better safe than sorry.
3. It's possible you aren't committing the update.
4. There's an easier way to write your time expression.

You might try this. It escapes the time variable, checks results explicitly after every sql operation, and commits the UPDATE. It also uses the simpler time expression.

```
 $query_set_invisible = "UPDATE scrims 
                            SET available='1' 
                          WHERE `time` > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE";

 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_set_invisible) 
                       || die "prepare failed: " . $mysqli->error;
 $stmt->execute()      || die "execute failed: " . $stmt->error;
 $mysqli->commit()     || die "commit failed: "  . $mysqli->error;
 $stmt->close()        || die "close failed: "   . $stmt->error;
```

}

Comment: I think the syntax should be UPDATE scrims SET available='1' WHERE `time` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)